# Check if 2 given numbers contain the same digits, even if are of different length or the digits repeat themselves

Tags: python

My problem today is to print this „Numerele sunt prietene” if 2 given numbers contain the same digits, even if the length of these numbers is different or some numbers repeat.

The problem is, if some large numbers are used, the program doesn't print anything. I'm looking forward to your solutions.

Here is my code (the method needed is made of 2 defs, one that checks the condition and 1 that prints the message, and 1 for (yes, it's a strange method)).

```
a = int(input("a → "))
b = int(input("b → "))

def numere(x, y):
    if x == y:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
def rasp(a):
    if a:
        return print(f"Numerele sunt prietene")
    else:
        return print(f"Numerele nu sunt prietene")

val = False
if a >= b:
    nr1 = a
    nr2 = b
else:
    nr1 = b
    nr2 = a

for i in str(nr1):
    for j in str(nr2):
        if numere(i, j):
            val = True
            if str(nr1).index(i) == len(str(nr1)) - 1 and numere(i, j):
                rasp(val)
            continue
    if val:
        val = False
    else:
        rasp(val)
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

if I understood correctly, you just want to know if two `int`'s have the same digits. Then just turn each `int` into a string then take the set of that string and compare the two sets of the two strings:

```
if set(str(a)) == set(str(b)):
    print("have the same digits")
else:
    print("don't have the same digits")
```

Or maybe I didn't understand your problem correctly.

Comment: This is correct, but it isn't quite the solution I'm looking for. The code must contain 2 defs and 1 for cycle.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to solve an assignment or homework then, and it is usually frowned upon for people to give you your assignment's solution ;)

Comment: However, you can easily adapt my solution to having some function definition, and instead of using `==` you can loop through each member of the set and compare each element in the set

Comment: I mean, the code works, but some cases need lots of memory (because this method is extremely inefficient). I just want to make this code work for every case, and honestly this is all I've been occupied with the last 2 days.

Comment: As long as `a` and `b` are already in memory, the set that represents them will have at most length 9 elements because there are 9 digits, so I don't see how is turning an `int` to a set is going to consume more memory.

Comment: Then why doesn't the code always give out a solution?

Comment: I am not here to debug your code, because I didn't really understand what you're trying to do there to be honest, I gave you a proper solution that does not really consume memory, and not outputting solution doesn't sound like a memory issue

Comment: I'm just going to quickly piggyback on here and say that at the time of this writing, two solutions have been posted here with both being a more efficient approach than the method that was originally attempted. The extra conditions make it sound like this is either a homework problem or some sort of misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can compare two digits converting them to string and using `set` and intersection.
`intersection()` method returns a `set` that contains the similarity between two or more sets:

```
_a = set(i for i in str(a))
_b = set(i for i in str(b))
_a.insersection(_b)
```

for a = 1425 and b = 225678343
intersection will be {'2', '4', '5'}

Comment: The intersection still doesn't tell you if both of them had the same digits or not, unless you still compare the result of the intersection again with `_a` and `_b`

Comment: @Fawaz.D intersection indeed returns you non empty set if they have same digits. If it is empty - no same digits. Simple logic

Comment: No, it will return nonempty if "some" of the digits are shared, and empty of non are shared, that still doesn't tell you if "all" are shared. Simple logic ;)

Comment: @Fawaz.D what do you mean "if all are shared"? The task was to check if 2 numbers have digits in common, as far as I understood. Intersection returns similarity of two sets, and that's the answer, or the question was if they have all similar digits even repeatable?

Comment: No, the question says "contain the same digits", so not just some digits shared, but they have the same digits regardless of whether some digits are repeated